# XML Update Nodes using Linq

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file with following entries, I want to update. I have gone through other related questions but not solving my issue.

```
<Movie>
    <Name>21</Name>
    <Year>2008</Year>
    <Genre>Drama</Genre>
</Movie>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go look at this question:

[Merging an XML file with a list of changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703528/merging-an-xml-file-with-a-list-of-changes/1703783#1703783)

I've linked to my answer because it contains a complete example - its probably slightly more complex than you need but still a trivially small number of line and combined with the debugger should give you all the elements (if you'll excuse the pun) you need to solve your problem